# Event Before the Record is changed in MS Access

Tags: events, ms-access-2010

I have an MS Access Form where I have two subforms. I need to be able to run a code/query before the record is discarded.
This DB is for tracking a hotel's sales and payments. The bounded form has the following layout:

1. First we have the main form with global fields like, ClientID, client name, address, bill date, restaurant bill, spa charges, etc.
2. Then I have the rooms subform (`Datasheet view`). This form has all rooms allotted to the guest. It also has the number of days charged and Rate fields.
3. Lastly I have a payments sub form (`DataSheet View`). It has all payments received from the guest.
    Last Tab index is for the payments Subform.
    I need to find the total amount the customer was billed. (`sum of all room rate X number of days + Money Spent in Spa + Restaurant Bill`). 
   I also need to find the sum of all payments. 
   If the `total payment` is different from `total bill` then I need to prompt the Operator to confirm the addition.
   I know the VBA codes and queries to process the above. But what I do not know is how to trigger this event. I tried AfterUpdate, but it is fired the moment I move to any Sub Form. I need the code to run after the Operator has made all changes and is ready to move to the next record. I am at a loss on how to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just place the function in the after update of the last field in the operator's workflow on the last subform?

Alternatively, place a check to run the code on your move next/prev buttons to ensure the operator has completed the entirety of the workflow?

Could you post a ss of the form(s) so I can get a visual picture :)?